# CodeFixProvider stops working after adding a simple method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

In Visual Studio 2015, Start new (VSIX) analyzer with codefix project. Don't build yet.

Add a simple method to the end of the CodeFixProvider class:

```
    void help()
    {

    }
```

Now build and see that the program works as expected.

Now add another simple class to the CodeFixProvider

```
    void help2()
    {

    }
```

Build and run. The lightbulb will not show anymore. Fixer is broken.
Comment out help2 method and everything starts working again.

What is going on?

Comment: wth is a codefix project... it doesnt seem default

Comment: C# Visual Studio 2015 extensibility template - Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)

Comment: I might be able to take a look when I get home, at work now. Thanks for replying with the full project name etc. :)

Comment: I had the same problem you need to delete you MEF Cache.  See my [question for assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44378000/1938988).  Please up vote if it helps you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Roslyn VSIX Extension Blows up from adding function in fix provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378000/roslyn-vsix-extension-blows-up-from-adding-function-in-fix-provider)

Comment: Help! I'm stuck in a time warp and duplicating questions from the future!

Comment: Actually, It looks similar but I never got an error. My extension just silently stops working. My system is a very fresh install of VS 2015 and I have only made about 7 vsix projects. I will try to replicate this on a different new system with a fresh install and see what happens and also see if I can get that exception in my current test project. Thanks!